# How to make plot options apply to all axes in a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I have something like

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10,10))
ax = ax.flatten()
ax[0].plot # ....
ax[2].plot # ....
ax[2].plot # ....
ax[3].plot # ....
plt.axis('scaled')
```

The `plt.axis` only applies to the last plot. What's the per axis equivalent?

And while I'm at it, more generally, matplotlib has been driving me insane this way for years. I have never found a clear way to go from plt.method to ax.method without having to dig deep in the docs. For instance there's `plt.title` then `ax.set_title` for some reason. Any pointers in general for this (teach a person how to fish).

Comment: From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html): 'scaled': Set equal scaling (i.e., make circles circular) by changing dimensions of the plot box. This is the same as `ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box', anchor='C')`. Additionally, further autoscaling will be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`pyplot.axis`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html) docs:

> 'scaled': Set equal scaling (i.e., make circles circular) by changing dimensions of the plot box. This is the same as `ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box', anchor='C')`. Additionally, further autoscaling will be disabled.